# Listar archivos mp3 con Google Apps en google Sheets Script desde Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

No se casi nada de java script, encontre un código que en esencia hace lo que quiero; lo he modificado y casi termino de personalizarlo, pero no he podido modificarlo totalmente para que haga lo que yo quiero, que es listar archivos de un solo tipo (MP3), lista todos los archivos.

Creo que tengo que modificar una de las siguientes lineas:

```js
var files = childFolder.getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
```

Escribi el sigueinte código pero no sé implementarlo y modificarlo ya que este me lista todos los archivos de Google Drive y solo necesito que me liste los archivos de cierta carpeta con sus subcarpetas por ejemplo .../Music/J

```js
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains 'mp3'")
  while (files.hasNext()){
    Logger.log(files.next())
```

Este es el codigo

```js
function onOpen() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files/Folders')
    .addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'listFilesAndFolders')
    .addToUi();
};

function listFilesAndFolders(){
  var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderId === "") {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder ID is invalid');
    return;
  }
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Year/Album","Track/Title","URL"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet );
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      data = [ 
//        parentName + " / " + childFolder.getName(),
        parentName,
        childFolder.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName  + " / " + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet);  
 
  }
};
```

Tambien dejo captura de pantalla del Hoja de calculo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que pueda echarme la mano? Tengo que rehacer todo el código? o se pueden modificar algunas lineas para que haga lo que quiero?

De antemano gracias por el apoyo

Comment: En el método `getChildFolders` mete dentro del bucle `while( files.hasNext() )` en primer lugar un `if (!childFile.getName().includes('mp3')) continue;` y debería funcionar. Básicamente, si el nombre no contiene .mp3 continuas con la siguiente iteración en vez de añadirlo

Comment: Gracias Bro @Benito-B, sirvió de maravilla, agradezco el apoyo recibido, marco como: RESUELTO

Answer (score 0):

Esta función devuelve un array con los nombres de archivo de una carpeta especifica y subcarpetas, puedes usarla como base y adaptarla a tu caso.

```
// Devuelve array de archivos de carpeta y carpetas internas según su extensión
function getArrayFiles(carpeta, extension) {
  const subCarpetas = carpeta.getFolders();
  let arrArchivos = [];
 
  // recorre sub-carpetas
  while (subCarpetas.hasNext()) {
    let childFolder = subCarpetas.next();
    
    // recorre archivos
    let archivos = childFolder.getFiles()
    while (archivos.hasNext()) {
      let archivo = archivos.next();
      let nombreArchivo = archivo.getName();
      
      // Verifica si el nombre del archivo tiene la extensión deseada
      if (nombreArchivo.endsWith(extension)) {
        arrArchivos.push(nombreArchivo);
      }
    }
    
    // llamada recursiva para sub-carpetas
    let masSubCarpetas = getArrayFiles(childFolder, extension);
    arrArchivos = arrArchivos.concat(masSubCarpetas);
  }
  
  return arrArchivos;
}
```

### Asi se usa

```
function test(){
  const idCarpeta = "ID_CARPETA";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idCarpeta);
  const arrArchivos = getArrayFiles(folder, ".mp3");
  Logger.log(arrArchivos);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Bro @Norberto Lopez, voy a implementar el código que tan amablemente me proporcionarte para aprender aún más, buen día. P.D. confirmo como funciona